# How and when to assume WLOG correctly?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, rearrangement-inequality

> Show that $$x^{2013}y+xy^{2013} \leqslant x^{2014}+y^{2014}$$

I know that this seems to be just an application of the rearrangement inequality, what I wanted to ask is that what does it actually mean when in this case one could say that "by symmetry" we can assume $x \leqslant y$ or "WLOG" $x \leqslant y$? This always trips me off a bit.

Comment: To me, WLOG means that you can prove the general case by the presented special case.

Answer (score 16):

$x$ and $y$ are just the names of the variables which play a symmetric role here. If you change their names, you get exactly the same exercise (try to write $x$ instead of every $y$ and vice-versa, then arrange). So, in the solution, you can always assume $x$ is the smaller one, because if it is not the case, the entire proof and exercise can be rewritten so that $x$ will be the name of the smaller one.

Comment: Another way to phrase it is that the proof of the case $y \leq x$ is nearly identical to the proof of the case that $x \leq y$, differing by the relabling $y \to x$ and $x \to y $.

Comment: This clears it up a bit! If you have the time could you show me an quick example of where one couldn't make this kind of assumption?

Comment: When $x$ and $y$ are not interchangeable. For example, if the question was $x^{2013}y+y^{2012}x\leq x^{2014} +y^{2014}$ then you cannot assume it -- they have different powers.

Comment: Another example is the inequality $(x + y)(x + 1) \geq 2 \sqrt{xy(x + y + 1)}$ which holds for each positive $x$ and $y$. This inequality does not look the same under an interchange of $x$ and $y$, so the proofs in the cases $x \leq y$ and $y \leq x$ probably won't essentially be the same.

Comment: @EhWha: when I was an undergraduate, before I knew about "wlog", that's exactly what I would do. I'd say, "to prove the 'opposite' case, relabel the variables and apply the previous argument"

Answer (score 6):

Let $P(x,y)$ denote the assertion that the inequality holds for $(x,y)$.

Then for all $x,y$, $P(x,y)\iff P(y,x)$.

So if you prove $P(x,y)$ for all $x,y$ such that $x\leq y$, you also get $P(y,x)$ for those same $x,y$'s.

But now $x,y$ are just names of variables, so you might as well say that we get $P(x,y)$ whenever $y\leq x$. Ha, but now we know $P(x,y)$ holds if $x\leq y$, and it holds if $y\leq x$.

Therefore it holds no matter what.

"To prove that for all $x$, $P(x)$ holds, we may wlog assume that $Q(x)$ holds" in general means that "for all $x$, $P(x)$" is *easily deducible* from "for all $x$ such that $Q(x)$ holds, $P(x)$ also holds".

Note that this contains some amount of subjectivity ("easily") and so whether "wlog" statements are relevant/valid will depend on who you're talking to.

For instance, imagine you're attempting a proof of Fermat's last theorem "if $n\geq 3$ and $xyz >1$, then $x^n+y^n\neq z^n$". Then to someone who has some amount of experience with number theory, you might say "assume wlog that $n=4$ or is an odd prime".

But of course, an actual proof should be required to show that this is enough : "wlog" just means "This additional proof should be easy for you".

Comment: Are you sure "4 or an odd prime" is a WLOG? (I don't have some amount of experience with number theory!) Obviously there are other cases, such as n=6. If they're already covered by a well-known number theory proof, then that ***isn't*** a case of "assume WLOG" because you ***are*** losing generality by making this assumption.

Comment: @user253751 : if you can prove the claim for $n=4$ and $n$ odd prime, then you can prove the statement for all $n$: it's a good exercise to verify that !

Comment: @user253751 It's stretching "WLOG" a bit. It's more a reduction proof than a WLOG proof. If $n=6$, then $n=2p$, where $p$ is an odd prime. If you can prove that it factors (i.e. whenever there's a solution for $2p$, there's a solution for $p$), then you can use the contrapositive (if there isn't a solution for $p$, then there isn't a solution for $2p$) to only have to prove the lack of solution for $p$.

Comment: If that's confusing, you might start with the idea that we can assume that there isn't a prime factor that $x, y,$ and $z all share, because the claim $(ap)^n+(bp)^n=(cp)^n$ is equivalent to $a^n+b^n=c^n$. So we might as well only consider the latter case, and by this logic we can remove any common factor until none are left.

Comment: Right. It's a reduction proof, not a case of "assume WLOG".

Comment: @user253751 : as I've tried to explain in my answer, wlog proofs are exactly reduction proofs, except you consider the reduction to be obvious - and of course the latter (the notion of "obvious") depends on you and your audience. So, wlog proofs will be different with a different audience in mind

Comment: *But of course, an actual proof should be required to show that this is enough : "wlog" just means "This additional proof should be easy for you".* 

So are you saying that WLOG makes a proof less "complete"? As in it is still thorough but you skip some small steps?

Answer (score 1):

To add some more concrete detail for this specific case to the fine given answers, suppose $x\le y$ and

$$x^{2013}y+xy^{2013} \leqslant x^{2014}+y^{2014}$$

now if $y\le x$ by $\bar x=y$ and $\bar y=x$ that is $\bar x\le \bar y$ we obtain

$$\bar y^{2013}\bar x+\bar y\bar x^{2013} \leqslant \bar y^{2014}+\bar x^{2014}$$

that is

$$\bar x^{2013}\bar y+\bar x\bar y^{2013} \leqslant \bar x^{2014}+\bar y^{2014}$$

which is equivalent to the first one.

Comment: what is $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$?